Can we remove or rewrite this paragraph in the tour?
While reading the tour, I stumbled upon this paragraph

Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.

That might make sense for Stack Overflow, but that doesn't make a lot of sense here. If you look at the questions list, you'll notice that all of them are clearly not someone who encountered a problem of a sort, and usually they aren't trying to do anything (other learning/satisfying curiosity).
Could this be removed or reworked to make sense for this site.

While some parts of the tour can be edited by site moderators, that specific paragraph is unfortunately not one of them; it's the same for every site on the network and can't be customised. If you want it to be customisable, you would need to put in a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange.
Source: I'm a moderator on another SE site and quickly popped open its own tour to double-check for myself.
